# Running MapProxy 1.15.1 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install MapProxy 1.15.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. I have roughly followed [the install documentation from mapproxy.org](https://mapproxy.org/docs/latest/install.html) with seems to be not fully compatible and slightly out of date.

To sum things up, it does not work. I get

```
# mapproxy-util --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mapproxy/bin/mapproxy-util", line 5, in <module>
    from mapproxy.script.util import main
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from mapproxy.script.conf.app import config_command
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/conf/app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .sources import sources
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/conf/sources.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mapproxy.srs import SRS
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/srs.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mapproxy.proj import USE_PROJ4_API
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 282, in <module>
    res = try_import()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 155, in try_libproj_import
    libproj = init_libproj()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 58, in init_libproj
    libproj = load_library('libproj')
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/util/lib.py", line 65, in load_library
    lib = load_library_(lib_name, locations_conf)
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/util/lib.py", line 69, in load_library_
    lib_path = find_library(lib_name)
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/util/lib.py", line 93, in find_library
    lib = _find_library(lib_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/util.py", line 341, in find_library
    _get_soname(_findLib_gcc(name)) or _get_soname(_findLib_ld(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/util.py", line 147, in _findLib_gcc
    if not _is_elf(file):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/util.py", line 99, in _is_elf
    with open(filename, 'br') as thefile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibproj.a'
```

What I get from util.py seems to be that it is intended to first try the parameter with prepended "lib" and then without. However, for some reason, it stops with an exception instead of continuing to try. This is also mentioned [on Github](https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy/issues/600), but without response.

I tried various methods to get around this, e.g. patching the code and placing a symbolic link. All of them worked partly. I ran into the next error:

```
# mapproxy-util --version
Found libproj >=5. Using this library without pyproj is deprecated and not fully supported. Please install pyproj >= 2.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mapproxy/bin/mapproxy-util", line 5, in <module>
    from mapproxy.script.util import main
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/util.py", line 29, in <module>
    from mapproxy.script.conf.app import config_command
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/conf/app.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .sources import sources
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/script/conf/sources.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mapproxy.srs import SRS
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/srs.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mapproxy.proj import USE_PROJ4_API
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 282, in <module>
    res = try_import()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 155, in try_libproj_import
    libproj = init_libproj()
  File "/root/mapproxy/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mapproxy/proj.py", line 66, in init_libproj
    libproj.pj_init_plus.argtypes = [c_char_p]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22: undefined symbol: pj_init_plus
```

In sum, several packages on Ubuntu 22.04 seem to be incompatible with MapProxy. I am currently running out of ideas how to solve this. Probably I would need an older version of libproj, but my knowledge does not suffice to install parallel versions of POSIX libraries. Is there some better/easy solution to this?

Addendum: I would appreciate some user to create a tag mapproxy and add it here. I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

if `mapproxy-util --version` gives an error, try

```
pip install pyproj
```